# odd/even function hybrid combination

Tags: functions

Every continuous smooth real function f(x) is either odd , even, or sum/difference of an even and odd (mixed like e.g., exponential) functions. Is this generally correct?

Can the even part of a mixed f(x) and odd part of another mixed g(x) be combined to make a new combo h(x)? If so how so and if not why not?

EDIT1:

Do such hybrid h(x) satisfy mean value theorem? Will there be no problem with computing their curvatures and inflection points? I asked this as I somehow feel that a mixed Taylor series has some of its " chemistry" or nature altered.

Comment: Are Taylor series allowed in the answer?

Comment: Yes, afik  that is the only way such a function is constituted.

Comment: Well, then it's a done deal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need smooth, or even continuous. Any function $f(x)$ is the sum of the two functions
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2}\quad,\quad \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2}
$$
where the first one is odd and the second one is even. If $f$ itself is odd or even, then one of the fractions above evaluates to $0$ and the other to $f(x)$. These parts can be freely added to the corresponding parts of other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
f(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}
= f_e(x) + f_o(x)
$$
This means
\begin{align}
(f + g)(x) 
&=
f(x) + g(x) \\
&= (f_e(x) + f_o(x) )+
  (g_e(x) + g_o(x) ) \\
&= (f_e + g_e)(x) + (f_o + g_o)(x) \\
&= (f+g)_e(x) + (f+g)_o(x)
\end{align}
If $f = F_e$ and $g = G_o$ then 
\begin{align}
(f+g)_e &= f_e + g_e = F_e + 0 = F_e \\
(f+g)_o &= f_o + g_o = 0 + G_o= G_o
\end{align}